# php and java in the same web application

Tags: java, php, web-hosting, php-java-bridge

I have a php webapp that get Facebook posts through API and save them into db. Then I have a java application that read this posts from db, classify them and save classification out into db.

How can I call java application from my php script??

[JavaBridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/index.php) Could be a solution, but are there web hosts that allow to use it ??

Thanks for any suggestion.

P.S.

The Java part is a processes that should be started by the PHP process on demand and stops when its task ended

Comment: You can run local Java programs just like any other executable, via [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

Comment: Is the Java part another running process, that is, for example a web application listening on some port, or a processes that should be started by the PHP process on demand and stops when its task ended? Please clarify this for a proper answer.

Comment: hi h7r, the second one: a processes that should be started by the PHP process on demand and stops when its task ended